# How to deploy nuxt js in production without hotreloading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt js has strange way of the rebuilding after deployment. On rebuilding the website is not avialable for several minutes, and i'm searching the best way to run this process at the background without reloading.

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Build nuxt.js to another directory then that containing your website.

When build is complete replace old website files with new build (you can write simple bash script for this).